# Postgresql: How query using array values from another table?

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I'm working with an existent database that have an array field (Phones) with the IDs from another table, I'm new to this kind of feature, how can I get all records of Public_Phone that are recorded into User->Phones Array?

User Table

```
+---------------------------------------+
|ID | User  | Phones(int array)  | Email| 
+---------------------------------------+
| 1 | 11922 | {12,23,56}         | none |
```

Public_Phone Table

```
+-------------------------------------+
|ID | Location | Color | AR | Line_FK |
+-------------------------------------+
```

Note: The database was upgraded recently to 9.4
Thanks in advance.

Taking in count the @nullReference comments I'm trying this

```
SELECT * 
FROM Public_Phone pp
WHERE pp.id IN (1,5)
```

That's work

But querying for user[3] using a subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Public_Phone pp
WHERE pp.id IN( SELECT Phones FROM User u WHERE u.id=3)
```

I got:

```
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = integer[]
```

Using

```
SELECT * 
FROM Public_Phone pp
WHERE pp.id = ANY( SELECT Phones FROM User u WHERE u.id=3)
```

Is the same

```
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

********** Error **********

ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = integer[]
```

Comment: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-in/

Comment: Thanks! I'm checking that now..

Comment: Seems that is needed cast the field in order to IN can get it :-( How can I do that?

Comment: You might try the ANY command vs IN as described in this post: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61520/how-to-do-where-x-in-val1-val2-in-plpgsql

Comment: I just updated my question with my test, I can't put this to work yet :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Public_Phone pp
JOIN User u ON pp.id = ANY(u.Phones)
WHERE u.id = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done more efficiently without a costly join.
All you needed to do is use UNNEST to convert the array into rows

```
SELECT * 
FROM Public_Phone
WHERE id IN( SELECT UNNEST("Phones") FROM User WHERE id = 3 )
```

Reference
https://lerner.co.il/2014/05/24/turning-postgresql-arrays-rows-unnest/